# ClipRRect is visible happening

Tags: flutter

First the image fades in as a rectangle. After that you can see the clipping happening. This is not what I want. In other words: first you see the image, and after that you see the corners 'popping of'.

Is there a way my image fades in with rounded corners. In other words: the clipping takes place before the image fades in.

Now this sounds strange, but is true: the undesired effect only takes place when the image has portrait orientation.

```
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    child: FadeInImage(
      placeholder: AssetImage("assets/img/loadingio.gif"),
      image: FileImage(_selectedFile),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I made a pen demonstrating it: https://codepen.io/leonvr/pen/WNrQVBo

Comment: I have had some help on Google Groups, but no good solution could be found. I created an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59155